# Dungeon Defenders, how do i use the portal gun. pc?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I have tried on every character that is able to carry the portal gun and if i shoot all i get is a weird noise and it will do nothing else. i have seen videos where it comes in to use like it would in the portal game but nothing has happened for me. any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dungeon Defenders wiki](https://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Aperture_Science_HPD)

> The Aperture Science HPD (ASHPD) is a level 30 **Huntress** and Series EV weapon.

Emphasis mine on the class you can use.

How it works:

> The ASHPD does no damage on its own. Instead, it can create two interdimensionally linked gateways, allowing players and monsters to move instantly between two spots on the map. Unlike the original Portal Gun, this version creates the portals in midair a few steps from the Huntress, and each portal is toggled open and shut with Primary Fire (for the blue portal) and Secondary Fire (for the orange portal).